# find a better control to display book content in a e-book reader

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create an e-book reader app, I have tried to use the control RichTextBox to display the content of a chapter in a book, while, it could not display the entire chapter, finally, I am told that the size of any control in windows phone is less then 2048px, and this causes the text located after 2048px (Height) in the RichTextBox could not be displayed. So, I need to find another one control to do such a thing. Is there any suggestion?

Further more, I want the control may meet the following requirements:

1. it could customize the fontsize, forecolor of the text displayed in it   (this may be the simplest one)
2. it could customize the background pic.
3. **it allow the user to select the text on it freely for copy** (this is the most important one of the 3)

Comment: May this could help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205757.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since an ebook is fundamentally a set of HTML pages, you should display your pages using a web control.

By the way, customizing font size etc. is not by any means trivial, because you end up trying to figure out whether or not and how to override CSS rules in the book.

You might want to check out http://openbookreader.codeplex.com/, although it seems to have  been inactive for a couple of years.